# How to split a string according to "\\" or "\"?

Tags: java, string

I want to split a string `"ABC\DEF"` ?
I have tried

```
String str = "ABC\DEF";
String[] values1 = str.split("\\");
String[] values2 = str.split("\");
```

But none seems to be working. Please help.

Comment: String str = "ABC\DEF"; ---> Compilation Error

Comment: Actually I have used escape sequence in the string "str".
str = "ABC\\DEF";

Comment: "ABC\DEF" if assign to string it returns compiler error like "Invalid escape sequence"

Comment: I am sorry. Effectively It comes out to be "ABC\DEF".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String.split() expects a regular expression. You need to escape each `\` because it is in a java string (by the way you should escape on `String str = "ABC\DEF";` too), and you need to escape for the regex. In the end, you will end with this line:

```
String[] values = str.split("\\\\");
```

The `"\\\\"` will be the `\\` string, which the regex will interpret as `\`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `String.split` splits a string by regex.

One correct way<sup>1</sup> to specify `\` as delimiter, in RAW regex is:

```
\\
```

Since `\` is special character in regex, you need to escape it to specify the literal `\`.

Putting the regex in string literal, you need to escape again, since `\` is also escape character in string literal. Therefore, you end up with:

```
"\\\\"
```

So your code should be:

```
str.split("\\\\")
```

Note that this splits on every single instance of `\` in the string.

#### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> Other ways (in RAW regex) are:

```
\x5C
\0134
\u005C
```

In string literal (even worse than the quadruple escaping):

```
"\\x5C"
"\\0134"
"\\u005C"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it:
String str = "ABC\\DEF";
String[] values1 = str.split("\\\\");

Answer (score -1):

```
final String HAY = "_0_";
String str = "ABC\\DEF".replace("\\", HAY);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str.split(HAY)));
```